# How to make a nested list to the one-dimensional?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to make a nested list to the one-dimensional without using modules?
Example:

```
input : [[[2]], [4, [5, 6, [6], 6, 6, 6], 7]
output: [2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7]
```

I wrote function

```
result = []
def flat_list(array):
    for x in array:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            flat_list(x)
        else:
            result.append(x)
            print(x)
    return result
```

I want to do it using only function and not using any variables outside. Thanks

Comment: What does your function give you compared to what you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a recursive function as below:

```
inList = [[[2]], [4, [5, 6, [6], 6, 6, 6], 7]]
def flatten(l):
    r = []
    for elem in l:
        if isinstance(elem,list):
            r += flatten(elem)
        else:
            r.append(elem)
    return r
print(flatten(inList))
```

Result:

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7]
```

Comment: With re: import re
list1 = [[[2]], [4, [5, 6, [6], 6, 6, 6], 7]]
str1 = str(list1)
print (str1)
str1 = re.sub(r'\\[|\\]', '', str1)
print (str1.split())